# Sending MMS does include the "sms_body"

Tags: android, mms

I am trying to send an image via an MMS using the following code

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi there"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```

It opens the Messaging apps and attach the message but it did not write the "sms_body" which is in my case "Hi there". Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
intent.putExtra("subject", "subject");
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi there");
intent.putExtra("address", "Phonenumber");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
intent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It says:  The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Comment: try after adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in intent

Comment: It does not work. It looks like it works on Handcent SMS. When the menu shows up and I choose Handcent, the sms body will be included. But it does not show in the Messaging app.

Comment: you are testing on real device?

Comment: working perfectlly on real device and make sure image size it small

Comment: I got it, Use

intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi there");
instead of

intent.putExtra("sms_body","Hi there");

Comment: +1 vote, i'm not saying accept my answer big thing is that your issue is solved and you can accept your answer thanks friend !!! :)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K you have to idea how to send audio file as a mms.if yes then give me some snippet.

Comment: @HarshidVasoya : see [this](http://code.google.com/p/modified-android-mms/source/browse/trunk/src/?r=11#src%2Fcom%2Fandroid%2Fmms) and let me known if this help u. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What seems to be working well is I just added EXTRA_TEXT (a solution which @yasserbn provided in a comment):

```
intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT, default_message);
```

in addition to:

```
intent.putExtra("sms_body", default_message);
```

And it seems to work whether it gets converted to multimedia message or sent as regular SMS.